# What did i do wrong? Html is confusing itself

Tags: php

I'm making a page where you have to enter a text in a textbox and the click send, another page will save it.
Also, on the first page, the text that was stored previously in the database, has to load. This is the code that i've got:

```
 <?php
$databaseid = 3;
$servername = "jog4fun.be.mysql";
$username = "jog4fun_be";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "jog4fun_be";

$gettitel1 = null;        
$gettext1 = null;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Id,Titel,Tekst FROM Teksten";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["Id"]== $databaseid ){
            $gettitel1 = $row["Titel"];
            $gettext1 = $row["Tekst"];
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();


$gettitel1 = strip_tags($gettitel1, '<br>');

$link1 = '<textarea id = "klein" rows="4" cols="50" name="titel3" form="usrform">' . $gettitel1 . '</textarea>';
$link2 = '<textarea id = "groot" rows="4" cols="50" name="text3" form="usrform">' . $gettext1 . '</textarea>';

echo $link1;
echo $link2;
?>
```

The problem is that it sends the text from textbox with name text3 as text1 with the post function.  Can someone figure out what's wrong with it? I've been tying for an hour and i did not find it.
Thanks for your time and help, 
Jonas

Comment: I cannot see where you tell us what is actually wrong with what this code does

Comment: I assume you are saying that the script only shows ONE row of data from your database is that correct? And you want to see all of them, is that right?

Comment: You could either add a little more detail to your question or answer the questions posed as a comment, but just disappearing does not help you or us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply here:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row["Id"]== $databaseid ){
        $gettitel1 = $row["Titel"];
        $gettext1 = $row["Tekst"];
    }
```

you overwrite the value of the two variables each time you iterate. So after this block of code you will keep stored the last values returned from the db. 
YOu should add to your query a WHERE clause to identify the one and only record you need so you will fetch only the relevant data. Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT Id,Titel,Tekst FROM Teksten WHERE Id='1'";
```

Comment: Or it could be OP wants to see all the rows he has stored in the database

Comment: then he should have more than one text box where he can store the data returned from the db I assume